# table-cell word-wrap not working with slashes

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap text in a fixed layout but it doesn't work when the text contains slashes.

Can this be fixed without inserting spaces from Javascript (pure CSS)?

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HgBhk/1/

```
Not working:
<div style="display:table; width:170px; background-color:cyan;">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell;word-wrap: break-word;">abfdbfdbfdb/dfbfdbdfbfbf/bdffbdbfdfbddfbdfbdfb</div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width:34px;  background-color:red;">xxxxx</div>        
    </div>
</div>

</br>
Working:
<div style="display:table; width:170px; background-color:cyan;">
    <div style="display:table-row">
        <div style="display:table-cell;word-wrap: break-word;">abfdbfdbfdb dfbfdbdfbfbf bdffbdbfdfbddfbdfbdfb</div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; width:34px;  background-color:red;">xxxxx</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using divs for tabular data? Use TABLES..Funny world eh~ people use divs for tabular data and tables for layouts

Comment: the reason the second case works is the spaces, not the absence of slashes. If you remove the spaces and have one long string (as the first case) it won't work either.

Comment: I'm not using tables because of the performance. I know there is a long discussion about this, pros and cons..

Comment: If I remove the space in second one, I am getting the text in a single line

Comment: @BogdanM. What do you know about performance?

Comment: @MrAlien people in my team saying..to many rows will slow down the layout, use divs...

Comment: @BogdanM. Using small tables as part of a page is not a performance killer.  The performance hit comes from using a table to layout the entire page, which means that the browser has to go through all the mark-up before rendering the page.  A one-row two-cell table is not an issue.  By using display: table, table-row and table-cell, you are directing the browser to render a table, so you are in effect using a table.  Tables can be useful when appropriate, no need to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `table-layout:fixed;` to the "table" div-element and assign a width to the cell to make it break lines:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgBhk/5/)

Comment: yes, but i don't want it to be fixed, i want to fill the remaining space

Comment: Then assign `width: auto;`, atleast give it some form of width :)  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgBhk/5/)

Comment: The first approach causes strings to be broken at arbitrary points; this is not acceptable in any normal conditions (e.g., for English-language words). The second part suggest using a property for hyphenation, citing w3schools, always an unreliable source. Hyphenation does not break after special characters.

Comment: I don't need hyphenation because it's about wrapping some paths

Comment: Breaking paths breaks the data, too; `foobar` is not the same as `foo bar` (which could be read as two paths), and breaking arbitrarily leaves it open which one is meant.

Comment: If it's just for showing paths, it's no problem. Besides, when you are going to need those paths later on, you should store them in an array or in a `data-path` attribute, not directly from the html-text inside an element

Comment: @GeenHenk: exactly what i'm doing..storing initial path to 'data-'

Answer (score 1):

Insert either a `<wbr>` tag or a zero-width space `&#x200b;` after each occurrence of a slash or other character that should be treated as allowing direct line break after it. The choice between these alternatives is a bit [complicated](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html), but since your code already fails to work on old versions of IE, you might just as well ignore them here too, and this would make `&#x200b;` the right choice. That is, you would write e.g.

```
abfdbfdbfdb/&#x200b;dfbfdbdfbfbf/&#x200b;bdffbdbfdfbddfbdfbdfb
```

The issue is at the character level, not a matter of styling.

A string containing no whitespace characters is normally indivisible in wrapping and should be that way, unless you can reliably make browsers either break at acceptable breaking points or hyphenate properly and use word division. A setting like [`word-wrap: break-word`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap) is meant for exceptional cases, emergency breaks when there is no good way to control wrapping and there is a need to avoid overflow.

Comment: this means I have to change the text..with javscript, right ? the initial question was how to do, without JS, plus I don't need hyphenation on paths. i think the answer is a little off topic

Comment: It depends on the context how you can modify the HTML document. Modifying it *is* the right way to handle wrapping properly (if wrapping is needed; in most cases when people put long pathnames or URLs into visible content, they should use something more normal, like short names). Paths should not be hyphenated of course; on the contrary, you should make sure they are not divided after “-” if such a character appears there. CSS *cannot* handle things like this (now or in the foreseeable future).